# ¿Cómo consultar en eloquent cuando hay tablas relacionadas? Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

¿cómo hacer una consulta cuando hay relaciones en las tablas?

Tengo las Tablas

**Alumnos**

| ID | Nombre | Apellido |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tony | Stark |

**Materias**

| ID | NOMBRE | ID_ALUMNO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Física | 1 |

**Direcciones**

| ID | Calle | Ciudad | ID_ALUMNO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Av.Reforma | Ciudad de México | 1 |

**Relaciones**

```html
class Alumno extends model
{
  
  protected $fillable =[
   'nombre','apellido',
  ];

  public function materias () {
  
    return $this->hasMany(Materia::class);
    
  }

  public function direccion(){
  
    return $this->hasOne(Direccion::class);
  }

}

class Materia extends model 
{
  protected $fillable =[
   'nombre','id_alumno',
  ];  

  public function alumnos () {
   
    return $this->belongsTo(Alumno::class,'id_alumno');
  
  }
  
}



class Direccion extends model
{
  protected $fillable=[
   'Calle','ciudad','id_alumno' 
  ];
  
  public function alumnos(){
  
    return $this->belongsTo(Alumno::class,'id_alumno');
  }

}
```

Normalmente para buscar un Alumno hago esto:

Buscador __________ Busco por nombre o por apellido, sino es que ambos

```html
  Alumno::where('name','like','%'.$busqueda.'%')
  ->orWhere('apellido','like','%'.$busqueda.'%')
  ->paginate();
```

Y Eso está bien, me regresa El Alumno relacionado a la búsqueda

El problema se presenta cuando quiero agregar más Palabras a mi buscador  o no solo más palabras sino buscar entre sus tablas relacionadas

| Caso | Buscador | Resultado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Tony stark Física | No me regresa nada |
| 2 | Tony ciudad de méxico | No me regresa nada |
| 3 | Stark, Ciudad de méxico | No me regresa nada |
| 4 | Tony stark, ciudad de méxico | no me regresa nada |
| 5 | Ciudad de méxico | No regresa nada |

Resultado esperados

**Caso 1**

Estoy ingresando el nombre y apellido eso debería se más que suficiente para regresarme las coincidencias (por ejemplo el nombre y apellido) en dado caso hasta  alumnos relacionados a esa materia de (Física)

**Caso 2**

Estoy ingreando el nombre y ciudad, Debería regresarme el alumno: pues al menos ciudad de méxico Nombre se relacionan

**Caso 3**

buscando por apellido y ciudad relacionada al alumno, estoy intentando que me regrese el alumno

**caso 5**

He puesto la ciudad de méxico, Necesito que me regrese todo los alumnos relacionados a esa  ciudad

Esos son los resultados que estoy intentando que me regrese, en todo esos casos.

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

Teniendo en cuenta que no puedo agregar opciones de una busqueda avanzada o personalizada, Necesito regresar datos(solamente teniendo un input text)

Algo así como lo que hace google Maps

que pones

Calle #, Municipio, Ciudad etc. Y te da resultados que al menos coincidan con esa entrada en el buscador.

Comment: Tendrías que probar con [`orWhereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). Sería ideal que edites tu pregunta para que el ejemplo del diagrama de la DB coincida con los nombres de los modelos que estás utilizando. Sino es medio confuso seguir el ejemplo.

Comment: Tambien deberias pasarte por como hacer relaciones entre los modelos, es mas sencillo

Comment: @azeós, Vale, cambiare esa imagen entonces y pondré los nombres

Comment: @Dohko19 ¿??? .. pues relaciones hay entre modelos jeje

Comment: @MarcosPortilloGarcia la pregunta no supone en realidad ser muy difícil, tus modelos tienen definidas las relaciones?, de ser así agregalo a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: @BetaM ya modifique la pregunta y si tengo las relaciones

Comment: De ser así agregalos por favor, así como lo que hayas tratado al momento

Answer (score 0):

Vas a tener que transformar la búsqueda ingresada en un array de palabras, para eso vas a separar por espacios pero no vas a guardar espacios vacíos.

Tomo una [respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28284621/1095101):

```php
$busqueda = request()->input('busqueda'); // Reemplazar por el nombre del campo de búsqueda

$palabras = preg_split('/\s+/', $busqueda, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

return Alumno::where(function ($query) use ($palabras) {
    foreach ($palabras as $palabra) {
        $query->orWhere('nombre', 'like', '%' . $palabra . '%')
            ->orWhere('apellido', 'like', '%' . $palabra . '%');
    }
})->orWhereHas('materias', function ($query) use ($palabras) {
    foreach ($palabras as $palabra) {
        $query->orWhere('nombre', 'like', '%' . $palabra . '%');
    }
})->orWhereHas('direccion', function ($query) use ($palabras) {
    foreach ($palabras as $palabra) {
        $query->orWhere('Calle', 'like', '%' . $palabra . '%')
            ->orWhere('ciudad', 'like', '%' . $palabra . '%');
    }
})->paginate();
```

No lo probé, pero debería servirte al menos para orientarte.

Probablemente te convenga usar algún paquete para [Laravel Scout](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout) como [TNTSearch](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver).